Issues with Fetching Data During Next.js Build and Using cache: "no-store"
I'm experiencing build errors in my Next.js application, and I'm hoping someone can help me understand and resolve the issues.
Error Details:
During the build process, I receive the following error:
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12502:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async globalThis.fetch (/path/.next/server/chunks/1638.js:1:36428)
    ...
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /.....
error Command failed with exit code 1.

I’m using fetch in my application with the cache: "no-store" option to address some caching-related issues, but this approach leads to several drawbacks, such as slower build times and increased load on the server.
Why is the build process failing? Could the use of cache: "no-store" be contributing to the problem, and if so, how?
Are there alternative solutions to cache: "no-store" that could help mitigate the caching issues while avoiding build failures?
How can I better handle data fetching during the build process to ensure that the application builds successfully without errors?
I’d appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve these issues.
Thank you!
